# Rewriting from a SEO friendly URL to another SEO friendly URL on the same site

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, seo

For our SEO needs in my company, we need to change some SEO URLs to another ones through 301.

**Example:**

`/seo/keywords-1-2-3/` to `/seo/mynew301page-1-2-3/`

Is there some Apache rewrite rule that I can specify that certain URLs should be redirected to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
Redirect 301 /seo/keywords-1-2-3/ /seo/mynew301page-1-2-3/
```

The above will redirect ALL requests for URLs that start with `/seo/keywords-1-2-3/` to `/seo/mynew301page-1-2-3/`. **For example:** `/seo/keywords-1-2-3/something?say=hello` ==> `/seo/mynew301page-1-2-3/something?say=hello`

If it has to be **precise match** (only `/seo/keywords-1-2-3/` and not `/seo/keywords-1-2-3/something`, then use this one:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/seo/keywords-1-2-3/$ /seo/mynew301page-1-2-3/
```

---

The same, but using **mod_rewrite**:

```
RewriteEngine On

# broad (base) match
RewriteRule ^/seo/keywords-1-2-3/(.*)$ /seo/mynew301page-1-2-3/$1 [R=301,L]

# exact match
RewriteRule ^/seo/keywords-1-2-3/$ /seo/mynew301page-1-2-3/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it n two ways:

1. .htaccess
2. httpd.conf

Mostly the .htaccess configuration method is used.

So you can use this code in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/seo/keywords-1-2-3/ /seo/mynew301page-1-2-3/ [R=301,L]
```